# Rails 3.1+, routes - can't add new route with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, parameters, routes

I use this route for display sign-up form:

```
match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
```

and this one work fine.

Now I want to add to `signup` link also the access code:

```
match '/signup/:access_code' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
```

But this route already doesn't work, I am getting the error

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
```

What caused this error? It's just adding one parameter to existing route...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as a working solution seems to be:

> match '/signup(/: access_code)' => 'users#new', :as => :signup